# How can i make a signle to another app?

Tags: android

I am starting to program at android studio
and i am thinking about an app that will prevent another app from opening
if the password is in-correcrt(another app crated by my on the cellphone- not another activity).
I thought about using a file but i think it wont work because you need to be specific on where the file is and i want my program to be dynamic.

Comment: you should show some code snippet too!!

Comment: Just curious. What's the difference between your app and password protection in screen lock..?